# What am i missing in this java regex for netbeans replace

Tags: java, php, netbeans

I want to alter thousands of lines in a project, the line is always one of these formats and is always in the middle of a line.

link() accepts upto 3 parameters and can look like these:

```
$this->url->link('this/path')
$this->url->link('this/path', '', true)
$this->url->link('this/path', 'something=' . $something, true)
$this->url->link('this/path', 'something=' . $something . '&other=' . $other, true)
```

I have a put together the following regex which correctly finds the lines I want as set out above with no problem.

```
// regex
\$this->url->link.*(, true)
```

I want to be able to remove empty parameters from the line so basically this means:

If parameters two and three match **'', true** remove them, otherwise remove just paramter three: **, true**

I tried these:

```
\$this->url->link.*(.*)
\$this->url->link.*($1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood your question, I'd use 2 different replacement operations, one to remove `'',true` and another to remove `,true`.

### deleting `'', true`

Search: `\$this->url->link\((.+), '', true\)`
Replace: `\$this->url->link($1)`

This should replace
`= $this->url->link('some/thing', '', true)`
with
`= $this->url->link('some/thing')`

---

### deleting `, true`

Search: `\$this->url->link\((.+),(.+), true\)`
Replace: `\$this->url->link($1,$2)`

This should replace
`=> $this->url->link('some/thing', 'variable data or empty', true)`
with
`=> $this->url->link('some/thing', 'variable data or empty')`

and also works for
`$this->url->link('some/thingthing', 'variable data', true)`
replacing it with
`$this->url->link('some/thingthing', 'variable data')`

Comment: Be extremely careful with mass replacements though, this shouldn't need to be said, but i feel like it's important enough to say anyway.

Comment: I have updated my question with real data, hopefully that will help, I think you were understanding my question just not with the right data. Sorry about that.

Comment: I fixed the answer, it was missing the backslash on the replace lines, also the '' is the same in both so no need to be replaced, so i removed them from search and replace so they are picked up automatically instead. Thank you very much for your answer, it really helped.

Comment: as far as i remember, the replace lines don't need backslashes, i might be wrong though.

Comment: It did for me, the line shows red without it, I am using NB8.2 / Ubuntu 16.04 it could just be a distro matter. In any case, it did work with the replace backslash so all is now done.